# how to serialize whole table and variable to php page

Tags: php, ajax

I am creating an inventory control system for my sales. i can serialize complete table successfully i have one problem  i have sell_price column in in table, retail price column is not there in the table.how can send the retail price to the php page.because i need to calculating profit at end the day sales.  i am sending all record to loading_add.php page through ajex. what i tried so far i wrote it below. how to send retail_price in to loading_add.php page.

```
retail_price : retail_price 

 var table_data = [];
    $('#product_list tbody tr').each(function(row,tr)
    {
        var sub = {
            'product_id' : $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
            'cat_id' : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
            'product_name' : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(),

              retail_price : retail_price

            'sell_price' : $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text(),
            'qty' : $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text(),
            'total_cost' : $(tr).find('td:eq(6)').text(),

        };
        table_data.push(sub);
    });

 $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url: '../php/product/loading_add.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',

        data: {data:table_data},
```

Comment: what value should be in retail price? any formula for it ?

Comment: retail_price  is coming from database sir  retail_price =Number(data[0].retail_price);     like the way i get it. each sell_price retail price should display please tell me the way to get profit

Comment: If it comes from the database, you don't need to send it in AJAX. The server can perform the database query to get it.

Comment: you can take hidden input for retail_price in each `tr` so you can get value for `retail_price` also.

Comment: enter the product code and get product name and sell price press enter key it is add in to the table   'product_name' : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(),   'sell_price' : $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text(),   retail price how to send i don't have any colum in table

Comment: yes sir retail_price hidden tr how to write it sir

Comment: when you display the data in table using `php loop` then include input for retail price also.

Comment: sir . can you write the code it is easy to understand thanks

Comment: So what is the problem here?

Comment: how to write hidden td to pass retail_price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One way is to take hidden input** if you are **not want to display the data to user still you needs it**.

for example, in your product listing table, you can take hidden input of retail price as you need it but dont have to display it to users.

so after executing mysql select query you can fetch data in your table as:

```
<table id="product_list" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>product Name</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>quantity</th>
        <th>total</th> 
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <?php foreach ($products as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['cat_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['product_name'] ?></td>
        <!-- below in sell price td we will take hidden input for retail price -->
        <td><input type="hidden" class="retail_price" value="<?php echo $row['retail_price'] ?>"><?php echo $row['sell_price'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['quantity'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['total_cost']; //or price * quantity ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And in your script you have mistaken as `$(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()`,

if you want to fetch first td then you should use `$(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()` because here `td` is array of elements and in array `index` always start with `0`.

so your script should be as:

```
$(function () {
    var table_data = [];
    $('#product_list tbody tr').each(function (row, tr)
    {
        var sub =
                {
                    'product_id': $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                    'cat_id': $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                    'product_name': $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
                    'sell_price': $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
                    'retail_price': $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').find('.retail_price').val(),
                    'qty': $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text(),
                    'total_cost': $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text(),
                };
        table_data.push(sub);
    });

 //here you can fire ajax request for adding record
});
```

**Another way is to take data attribute for your needed value**

in same example as above you can take data attribute in your td as

```
 <td data-retail_price="<?php echo $row['retail_price'] ?>"><?php echo $row['sell_price'] ?></td>
```

and in your script you can get data attribute's value as in same script as above:

```
 'retail_price': $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').data('retail_price'),
```

Comment: <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control pro_price" id="sell_price" name="sell_price"
                               placeholder="price" disabled>
                    </td>  this is the sell price text box how to include retail price and hidden here

Comment: in same `<td>` you can also include another input as `<input type="hidden" class="retail_price" value="<?php echo $row['retail_price'] ?>" >` or take `data` attribute.